# CountDownTimer with ProgressBar, continuing progressbar when restarting the app

Tags: android, kotlin, progress-bar, countdowntimer, android-progressbar

I have a ProgressBar that shows the progression of a CountdownTimer. The ProgressBar works except for when I close the app and start it again. If I do that, the ProgressBar begins from zero. It doesn't continue where I left off.

I have a variable to maintain the countdown in milliseconds. I manage to maintain it correctly by using SharedPreferences in the OnStop and OnStart methods. But how do I use this variable correctly for maintaining the progress of the ProgressBar?

```
private fun startCountdown() {

    var i = 1

    object : CountDownTimer(timeLeftInMilliseconds, 1000) {

        override fun onTick(millisUntilFinished: Long) {

            timeLeftInMilliseconds = millisUntilFinished
            
            i++

            myProgressBar.progress = (i * 100 / (40000 / 1000)).toInt()
            //Instead of 40000 here, I have tried to use the variable 
            //timeLeftInMilliSeconds or millisUntilFinished, but that doesn't work. 
        }

        override fun onFinish() {
            progressBarOutOfLikesTimer.progress = 100;
            timeLeftInMilliseconds = 40000
        }
}
```

Comment: Show more of your code, like the onStart and onStop functions you mention. My guess would be that your onStop method does not get called.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this `i` variable is adding unnecessary complication. You can directly calculate the fraction of the bar to fill from the remaining time divided by total time. I use `toDouble()` here to be sure we aren't doing integer math and getting unwanted truncating. I'm assuming `max` of the ProgressBar is 100. You should multiply the time fraction by whatever the `max` is.

```
private fun startCountdown() {

    object : CountDownTimer(timeLeftInMilliseconds, 1000) {

        override fun onTick(millisUntilFinished: Long) {
            timeLeftInMilliseconds = millisUntilFinished
            myProgressBar.progress = (100 * (1.0 - millisUntilFinished.toDouble() / 40000)).toInt()
        }

        override fun onFinish() {
            progressBarOutOfLikesTimer.progress = 100;
            timeLeftInMilliseconds = 40000
        }
}
```

Comment: So it works in principle now,  but how do I reverse it so the ProgressBar slowly fills? With your example it starts with a full ProgressBar and slowly "empties" itself counter-clockwise. I want it to fill clockwise.

Comment: Oh, right. Just subtract the fraction from 1 to invert it. I updated it above.

Comment: That's not it, now it doesn't display any progress at all.

Comment: Are you sure you copied it exactly? I made a sample project with this code and it works fine.

Comment: My bad. You're right. I had a parenthesis in the wrong place.. geez.